# How to embed videos with ads using jwplayer to facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, jwplayer, flowplayer

Is there away to embed videos with pre roll or overlay ads to facebook using jwplayer or flowplayer like youtube does?

Comment: I don't think so. I believe FB blocks that, for obvious reasons. They have some sort of "arrangement" with YouTube to make it possible.

Comment: Yeah, FB blocks that.